# Best alternative for Trigger in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I got a condition that, whenever the 3 columns

```
  (`OMIMAGE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `suspendedCase` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `futureDated` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,)
```

gets data, insertion into another table needs happen. All the 3 columns must get data.

Is there any other best alternative instead of using trigger.

Comment: Inside of mysql you have to use triggers. If your hosting does not allow to use them you need to ensure this in you program logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On database level, you have nothing but trigger for this case.

There is another **tiny** feature which you can use for ensuring that value `is not null`:

```
create table tbl (
    OMIMAGE varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    suspendedCase varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    futureDated varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
```

But in this case you can only ensure that value is not null, you cannot guarantee that it isn't empty string etc...